# foreach loop with different classes for even / odd posts

Tags: php, css, laravel, loops

I'm trying to display odd and even posts, with different classes and sub-classes in a `foreach` loop in Laravel. I can't find anything in the documentation that suggests how to pull odd data differently from even data in a `foreach` loop.

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <li  class="timeline-inverted">
      <div class="timeline-badge primary" ><a title="{{ $post->created_at }}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time invert" id=""></i></a></div>
      <div class="timeline-panel">
        <div class="timeline-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/2efde286ce7b0171a0dfedd1f3cff984?s=80&amp;d=&amp;r=G"">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                  <a> {{ $post->title }} </a> shared 6 hours ago
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-heading">
          <div class="videowrapper">
              <iframe height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4PXXQzME5no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-body">
          <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>

        </div>

        <div class="timeline-footer">
          <div class="media">
            <a class="pull-left" href="#">
              <img class="media-object" src="" />
            </a>
            <div class="media-body">
              <p>Comment</p>
              <a href="#">November at 8:15am</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="media">
            <a class="pull-left" href="#">
              <img class="media-object" src="" />
            </a>
            <div class="media-body">Comment </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class="media">
            <a class="pull-left" href="#">
              <img class="media-object" src="" />
            </a>
            <div class="media-body">Comment </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="timeline-badge primary" ><a title="11 hours ago via Twitter"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time invert" id=""></i></a></div>
      <div class="timeline-panel">
        <div class="timeline-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/2efde286ce7b0171a0dfedd1f3cff984?s=80&amp;d=&amp;r=G"">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                  <a> {{ $post->title }} </a> shared 6 hours ago
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-heading">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img.png" />
          <div class="timeline-images">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                <img src="img/img1.png" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                <img src="img/img2.png" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                <img src="img/img3.png" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-body">
          <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>             
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: You can use CSS to do that, look for nth child

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add different class to even and odd divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540141/add-different-class-to-even-and-odd-divs)

Comment: Some of the code was removed after I posted it, but I need to pull post->title and post-> body for each list item structure and their different

Comment: wow that was fast replies:D

Comment: what about assigning a 2 variables with $post->title and and adding 2 on the first and 2 on the second variable, though the second variable would need to start at 2, to always be even, the first would likely always be odd when adding 2, though I'm not sure how the code would fit in, because it need to include dynamic post titles into the classes and sub classes

Comment: I'm still not sure how to wrap the css around the title and body variables, pulling post->title in odd and even instances would still be the same thing

Comment: You need to change your mindset. Just output the posts the way you are used to do and make the differences by use of CSS. Lookup nth child information.